# datatables.bootstrap.js is giving eror in IE8

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have used dataTables.bootstrap.js and DataTables 1.10 in my application.It's working fine with Mozilla and google chrome.It's throws an exception with IE7 and IE8.Below is my html code

```
<head runat="server">
<title>Simpluris: Class Action Settlement Administration. Forming Knowledge from Information.
</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- the following line of code forces IE9 to behave like edge, which fixes many bugs in formatting -->
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
<%--Css Reference--%>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/css/dataTables.responsive.css">
<link href="../Bootstrap/libraries/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<link href="../Bootstrap/Bootstrap-General.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../css/secure.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%--Jquery Reference--%>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>   
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/1.0.6/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/api/fnProcessingIndicator.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<%--  [if lt IE 9]>--%>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.js"></script>
<%-- <![endif]--%>
<%--loading local files if CDN is not working--%>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //     JS Fallback
    //<![CDATA[
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/libraries/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/DataTables-1.10.7/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/TableTools/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/DataTables-1.10.7/extensions/Responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/libraries/1.11.3/fnProcessingIndicator.js"><\/script>');
    if (typeof ($.fn.modal) === 'undefined') { document.write('<script src="../JQuery/libraries/1.11.3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"><\/script>') };
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/libraries/1.11.3/fnProcessingIndicator.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/html5.js"><\/script>');
    (window.jQuery) || document.write('<script src="../JQuery/respond.js"><\/script>');
    //]]>
</script>

<script src="../Bootstrap/libraries/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.customselect.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
<%--Task 1399:  Session Timeout Message--%>
<script src="../JQuery/jquery.idle-timer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../JQuery/timeout-dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!--[if IE]><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/ie.css" media="screen"/><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/globalfunctions.js"></script>
<!-- for jquery... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/tooltipsy.source.js"></script>
<!-- for the tooltips... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script src="../JQuery/Custom/Util.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>

</head>
```

> **Error is** : defaults' is null or not an object

Above error is giving in DataTables.Bootstrap.js file

```
/* Set the defaults for DataTables initialisation */
$.extend( true, DataTable.defaults, {
    dom:
        "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",
renderer: 'bootstrap'
} );
```